# Unity Cloud Build: Error: Unrecognized Project

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, cloud

This is my first time using Unity Cloud Build.  I'm using BitBucket with SourceTree, I've also tried it with GitHub, but I keep getting the same error:

> Error: unrecognized project! Please check your app configuration - if this is a Unity application, We expect your "Project Subdirectory" to be set to the path which directly contains the ProjectSettings and Assets directories. For a native app, this should be set to the path which directly contains the project file (.xcodeproj, project.properties, etc).

The project itself is simple, just one 3d character model and a basic walk animation just to make sure things were at a minimum.  If anyone could help that would be great!

Here is the full log.

```
1: Running Prebuild steps
2: Removing bvr
3: Successfully uninstalled bvr-1.2.11
4: 1 gem installed
5: done.
6: bvr 1.2.12
7: bvr-api 0.2.4
8: Cloning the remote Git repository
9: Cloning repository ssh://git@bitbucket.org/jsmccloud/gm_animation_test.git
10: Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@bitbucket.org/jsmccloud/gm_animation_test.git
11: Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@bitbucket.org/jsmccloud/gm_animation_test.git
12: Checking out Revision d84217f8e82b1bedcd64256ae88a38b9226beb9b (refs/remotes/origin/master)
13: First time build. Skipping changelog.
14: Calculated Workspace Size: 308.73 MiB
15: PATH               | SIZE      
16: /GM_Animation_Test | 308.73 MiB
17: postcheckoutstatus finished successfully.
18: Error: unrecognized project! Please check your app configuration - if this is a Unity application, We expect your "Project Subdirectory" to be set to the path which directly contains the ProjectSettings and Assets directories. For a native app, this should be set to the path which directly contains the project file (.xcodeproj, project.properties, etc).
19: Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
20: postbuildstatus finished successfully.
21: Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Is there project setting, in your repo.

Comment: You have to have *assests, projectsetting* in your repo.

Comment: Yes, I have assets, projectsettings and library directories. I basically dragged the entire directory that contained all my project files and assets into the github directory. So everything should be there.

Comment: Is your project top level containing the Assets and Project Settings? That is you do not have a folder then inside of it, the needed folders.

Comment: What do you mean drag? you use a git gui client?

Comment: I mean that after I created the repository online and then sent it to the desktop client, where the folder was created, I then opened up my windows explorer (file manager) navigated to my project folder for Unity, and dragged those files into the directory that was created from my git client.  I then commit the changes and pushed them back to github.  Here it is on github if you need to see the folder structure and files: https://github.com/jsmccloud/gm_animation_test

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed the problem:

In my Unity project I set the following settings:
Under Edit>Project Settings>Editor

Set Version Control Mode to Visible Meta Files
Set Asset Serialization Mode to Force Text

Save project and close Unity.  Apparently, leaving Unity open when I copy my files over to my repo directory had caused problems.

Everything seems to work fine now.